# sql query join left 3 tables

Tags: mysql, sql, date, join, where-clause

Something is not working right, but I don't get it.

I want to list all events fromt table `evinvite`, listed in `evgroups` wich are not dated more than 7 days ago, and do not have any feedback in the `evfeedback` table.

```
SELECT 
  t1.evid
FROM 
  evinvite t1
LEFT JOIN evfeedback t2 
  ON t2.evid = t1.evid
  WHERE t2.evid IS NULL AND userid ='".$uzer."' AND status=9
LEFT JOIN evgroups t3
  ON t3.evid = t1.evid
  WHERE t3.data >= DATE(NOW()) + INTERVAL -7 DAY AND t3.data <  NOW() + INTERVAL 0 DAY
```

Comment: can you post your table structure?

Comment: you can not have 2 `where` clauses

Comment: You only can have one `WHERE` clause per `SELECT`. You got two. It's unclear what you want to do. Likely you want to have the predicates from the `WHERE`s in the respective `ON`s. Another option are subqueries or a common `WHERE` clause for the whole `SELECT`. For further advise edit the question and add the table structure as `CREATE TABLE` statements, sample data as `INSERT INTO` statements and the desired result.

Answer (score 2):

You are mixing `WHERE` and `ON` clauses.

To filter out events having feedbacks, you want the `t2.evid IS NULL` condition in the `WHERE` clause.

Also you probably want an `INNER JOIN` instead of a `LEFT JOIN` on event groups.

Try :

```
SELECT 
    t1.evid
FROM 
    evinvite t1
    LEFT JOIN evfeedback t2 
        ON t2.evid = t1.evid
        AND userid ='".$uzer."' 
        AND status=9
    INNER JOIN evgroups t3
        ON t3.evid = t1.evid
        AND t3.data >= DATE(NOW()) + INTERVAL -7 DAY
    AND t3.data >= DATE(NOW()) + INTERVAL -7 DAY
WHERE 
    t2.evid IS NULL
```